Plot scatter chart y = Ch1 to Ch3 values, z = Date, group them with Mode
I have pandas dataframe like below,



Date
Serial
Mode
Ch1
Ch2
Ch3




2024-06-01
RMD2348
A
12
18
18.1


2024-06-02
RMD2401
B
13.8
16.1
14.1


2024-06-01
RMD2411
A
11.8
17.2
16.2


2024-06-03
RMD2406
C
10.5
16.99
17.2


2024-06-02
RMD2424
B
12.8
16.02
18.2


2024-06-02
RMD2419
A
12.56
17.2
11.9



if I use below code, manage to display Ch1 to Ch3 only, no idea how to group them to Mode A, B, C
import plotly.graph_objs as go

ch_columns = ['Ch1','Ch2','Ch3']

for ch in ch_columns:
    channel = go.Scatter(name=ch,
                         x=dff['Date'],
                         y=dff[ch],
                         text=dff['Serial'],
                         mode='markers')

    channels.append(channel)

layout = dict(
              title = 'Channels / Time',
              xaxis = dict(type = 'date',
              title = 'Date',
              tickformat = '%Y/%m/%d',
              ticklen = 5,
              dtickrange = 14,
              tickmode = 'auto',
              rangeslider = dict(visible=True)),
              yaxis = dict(title = 'Channel Values'),
              )
fig = dict(data=channels, layout=layout)
fig.show()


It's not clear, what do you mean exactly by "how to group them" ? Do you have any chart example or a sketch that better illustrates what you want to obtain ?

The scatter display Ch1 to Ch3 for all Serial and all mode, but I want to let said just Mode either A, B or C only to be appear at the chart by using plotly built option is any.
